# How to make "M-x man" buffers use all the available width of the screen?

Tags: buffers, man

## The problem

When opening `man` in a terminal emulator, `man` tries to use as much width as possible. However, when opening `man` inside `emacs`, `man` doesn't use all the width (even after `Man-update-manpage` has been executed.)

In the gif shown below, I open the `emacs` manual page in a terminal emulator and we can see that the manual page uses all the available width. However, this doesn't happen when this manual page is opened inside `emacs`. The instance of `emacs` shown in the GIF was opened by executing `emacs -Q`.

[image]

## The question

How can I make `M-x man` display manual pages so that they use all the available width?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `(setq Man-width-max 160)`, or `(setq Man-width-max nil)`.

The documentation of `Man-width-max` says:

```
This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 27.1 of Emacs.

Maximum number of columns allowed for the width of manual pages.
It defines the maximum width for the case when ‘Man-width’ is customized
to a dynamically calculated value depending on the frame/window width.
If the width calculated for ‘Man-width’ is larger than the maximum width,
it will be automatically reduced to the width defined by this variable.
When nil, there is no limit on maximum width.
```