# How can I set man-width for long lines in man-mode?

Tags: man

I am using GNU Emacs 28.2.50 along with `emacsclient`.

I am using https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ManMode. When I have a smaller width size in a iTerm terminal, `man-mode` kind of messed up for long lines. The comparasion could be seen here:

=> Upper window is in emacs.
=> Lower window is in less where original (`command man wget`) is applied.

[image]

In emacs, for the long line, it continues from second line without a TAB. For example:

```
DESCRIPTION
    GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web.  It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, 
as well as retrieval through
       HTTP proxies.
```

should be:

```
DESCRIPTION
    GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web.  It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well 
    as retrieval through HTTP proxies.
```

---

Even I have set `Man-width to nil` and `Man-width-max to 80` Link: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62535/18414, it is not helped.

```
(define-key Man-mode-map "q" 'my-kill-emacs)
(define-key Man-mode-map "Q" 'my-kill-emacs)

(setq Man-width 80)
(setq Man-width-max 80)
```

The way I run `man-mode` page in `emacs`:

```
man () {
    emacsclient -cqut -nw -e "(let ((Man-notify-method 'bully)) (man \"$1\"))";
}
```

I am not sure what is preventing `Man-width-max` to be applied.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: Currently I am using GNU Emacs 28.2.50

Comment: Do you see the same problems if you don't use your `emacsclient` script?  I.e. just using `M-x man`?  If so, you should simplify the question by eliminating the client/server aspect.  If not, then clarify the difference.

Comment: Also, does typing `u` in the man buffer to refresh it change the formatting?  And what does `C-h v Man-width-max` report in that buffer?

Comment: Last question: Do you see the same in other terminals? (i.e. not iTerm)

Comment: I have tried `Terminal` is macOS and I observed the same behavior.  `Man-update-manpag`  (`u`) did not do anything. `Man-width-max` reported as 80. I see the same problem if I don't use `emacsclient ` and instead use `emacs -nw`

Comment: Please simplify your question to the `emacs -nw` case, without the custom shell script.

Comment: Clarify whether you see the same thing starting from `emacs -Q` and setting those user options manually.  If you do, simplify your question further to that case.  If you do not, then state that in your question (and probably start bisecting your config at that point).

Comment: Assuming Emacs is compiled with GUI support, please also clarify whether the terminal is actually a factor at all -- do you see the problem in GUI frames?

Comment: Pleasae note that there is no GUI support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `Man-width-max` to 0 instead of `nil`.

Comment: I don't understand how this helped vs setting `Man-width-max` to 80.  A value of zero looks to be an undocumented way of not using the max width at all; but when it *is* used it acts as a limit, and a limit of 80 would not produce the longer lines seen in the screenshots.